# Use schema search path in views

Tags: postgresql, schema

I am experimenting a little with PostgreSQL schemas and found that the search path doesn't seem to be used in views. I have two schemas, one called `bf` and `public`. My search path is set as `bf,public`. Both schemas have the same tables, the table in `public` is empty.

When using this view:

```
CREATE VIEW public.testview(data1, data2)
AS
  SELECT data1, data2 FROM the_table;
```

always only data from `public` (i.e. nothing) is shown.

I expect the data from `bf`, because `bf.the_table` is found first, according to the search path.

**Update** the view seems to  automatically include the tablename including the schema name. When creating and omitting the schema name, it shows after changing the schema search path.

Comment: Maybe what you want can be done with [rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules.html). (AFAIK a view is translated to a rule too, so you might want to start with that rule and try to modify it to use a variable schema.)

Comment: @stickybit I looked at the documentation, but haven't found a way to implement what I want, could you perhaps elaborate?